# Behavior of InputStream vs. CharacterStream

Tags: filereader, fileinputstream

I am trying to understand the difference between behavior of any byte oriented stream (say FileInputStream) and any Character oriented stream (say FileReader).

I went through the following: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html)

First program:

`import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}
`
**Second program:**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
```

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    FileReader inputStream = null;
    FileWriter outputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new FileReader("xanadu.txt");
        outputStream = new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt");

        int c;
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

It says:
in CopyCharacters, the int variable holds a character value in its last 16 bits; in CopyBytes, the int variable holds a byte value in its last 8 bits.

My question is: I wanted to check this above sentence so printed value of c (integer defined in program) while it was being copied. Now the value of c must be different at consecutive reads because in byte stream it reads byte by byte, so have byte value, while in character stream it reads character by character, so has character ASCII value. But it is giving same values of c. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to think it in different way, If my source file has only one character say 'a'.

Now CopyBytes should run while loop atleast 2 times because character takes 2 bytes. But it is running only once.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
```

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
//in CopyCharacters, the int variable holds a character value in its last 16 bits; 
//in CopyBytes, the int variable holds a byte value in its last 8 bits.

public class CopyCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    FileReader inputStream = null;
    FileWriter outputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new FileReader("source.txt");
        outputStream = new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt");

        int c;
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println("one");
            outputStream.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Here one is printed only once